# Read The Docs Build on GitHub Push not building - no error message

Tags: python, git, github, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I've had a Build The Docs auto build which is triggered by a webhook from Git hub. It's worked before, but suddenly today is not working any more, and I'm not getting any obvious error messages (build log below). It seems to be erroring after doing a `git clone` without actually running any build commands?

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/kammetherell/py4pa)

```
Read the Docs build information
Build id: 23541682
Project: py4pa
Version: latest
Commit: None
Date: 2024-02-23T16:04:42.332307Z
State: finished
Success: False


[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:42.934047Z, end-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:43.259609Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/kammetherell/py4pa.git .
Cloning into '.'...

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:43.280323Z, end-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:43.799255Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git fetch origin --force --prune --prune-tags --depth 50 refs/heads/release:refs/remotes/origin/release
From https://github.com/kammetherell/py4pa
 * [new tag]         0.0.3      -> 0.0.3
 * [new tag]         0.0.4      -> 0.0.4
 * [new tag]         0.0.5      -> 0.0.5

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:43.910368Z, end-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:43.973770Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git checkout --force origin/release
Note: switching to 'origin/release'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 62a9c8f switch to pyproject.toml

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:43.999721Z, end-time: 2024-02-23T16:04:44.060829Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git clean -d -f -f
```

readthedocs.yaml:

```
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Set the version of Python and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-lts-latest
  tools:
    python: "3.9"

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
   configuration: docs/source/conf.py

# If using Sphinx, optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF
# formats:
#    - pdf

# Optionally declare the Python requirements required to build your docs
python:
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
  system_packages: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `system_packages: true` has been deprecated. If you remove it from your YAML file your build will work.

Read more about this deprecation at https://blog.readthedocs.com/drop-support-system-packages/